# How to apply validations on following angularJs code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to apply the validations in following angularjs CODE
I have tried to apply following validations 
but it is not working properly 
So tell me the error in code to apply validations

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Index</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope , $http) {
        refreshData();

        function refreshData(){
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url:'http://localhost:8081/SpringWithAngularJs/rest/countries.json'
                    }).success(function(data)
                        {

                        $scope.posts = data;

                        });
        }
        $scope.form = {
                countryName : "pp",
                population : "1000"
                    };
        $scope.add=function(){
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url:'http://localhost:8081/SpringWithAngularJs/rest/countries/create/'+$scope.form.countryName+'/'+$scope.form.population
                }).success(function(data){
                    refreshData();
                    });
            }
        $scope.remove=function(data){
            $http({
                method: 'DELETE',
                url:'http://localhost:8081/SpringWithAngularJs/rest/countries/delete/'+data
                }).success(function(data){
                    alert('Country Deleted');
                    refreshData();
                    });
        }
    });
    </script>
    </head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
<h1>Country List</h1>
    <table border="">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Country Id</th>
                <th>Country Name</th>
                <th>Country Population</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tr ng-repeat="c in posts">
            <td>{{c.countryId}}</td>
            <td>{{c.countryName}}</td>
            <td>{{c.population}}</td>
            <td><button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <h1>Add Country</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Country Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="form.countryName" required/></td>
            <td><span style="color: red" ng-show= "myForm.form.countryName.$dirty && myForm.form.countryName.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="myForm.form.countryName.$error.required">Country Name is required</span></span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Country Population:</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="form.population"/></td>
            <td><span style="color: red" ng-show= "myForm.form.population.$dirty && myForm.form.population.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="myForm.form.population.$error.required">Country Name is required</span></span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.form.countryName.$dirty && myForm.form.countryName.$invalid || myForm.form.population.$dirty && myForm.form.population.$invalid" ng-click="add()">Add</button></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

or tell me how to debug the error?

Comment: use console.log($value); to get value to debug, you have to know the value get inside $scope function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Changes in Html -

You have missed required Tag for population. Also in angular validation are working with

> input name tag

```
   <td><input type="text" name="countryName" ng-model="form.countryName" required/></td>
            <td><span style="color: red" ng-show= "myForm.countryName.$dirty && myForm.countryName.$invalid">

   Country Name is required</span></td>
```

For button -

```
<td><button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="add()">Add</button></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont give name to the control. and also use **formName.ControlName** to show error. You used formName.ModelName that is not valid. See my code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Index</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope , $http) {
        refreshData();

        function refreshData(){
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url:'http://localhost:8081/SpringWithAngularJs/rest/countries.json'
                    }).success(function(data)
                        {

                        $scope.posts = data;

                        });
        }
        $scope.form = {
                countryName : "pp",
                population : "1000"
                    };
        $scope.add=function(){
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url:'http://localhost:8081/SpringWithAngularJs/rest/countries/create/'+$scope.form.countryName+'/'+$scope.form.population
                }).success(function(data){
                    refreshData();
                    });
            }
        $scope.remove=function(data){
            $http({
                method: 'DELETE',
                url:'http://localhost:8081/SpringWithAngularJs/rest/countries/delete/'+data
                }).success(function(data){
                    alert('Country Deleted');
                    refreshData();
                    });
        }
    });
    </script>
    </head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
<h1>Country List</h1>
    <table border="">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Country Id</th>
                <th>Country Name</th>
                <th>Country Population</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tr ng-repeat="c in posts">
            <td>{{c.countryId}}</td>
            <td>{{c.countryName}}</td>
            <td>{{c.population}}</td>
            <td><button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <h1>Add Country</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Country Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="form.countryName" name="countryName" required/></td>
            <td><span style="color: red" ng-show= "myForm.countryName.$dirty && myForm.countryName.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="myForm.countryName.$error.required">Country Name is required</span></span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Country Population:</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="form.population" name="population"/></td>
            <td><span style="color: red" ng-show= "myForm.population.$dirty && myForm.population.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="myForm.population.$error.required">Country Name is required</span></span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.form.countryName.$dirty && myForm.form.countryName.$invalid || myForm.form.population.$dirty && myForm.form.population.$invalid" ng-click="add()">Add</button></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```